# Magento store not working on localhost

Tags: php, apache, magento, localhost

I am trying to run a magento store that works on live server in my localhost wamp server. I am using windows 7 x64 with wamp that includes: Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.13 and MySQL 5.5.24. 
This is the following error that i get when i try to run the store:

```
    Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version.
    Magento supports PHP 5.2.0 or newer. Find out how to install Magento using PHP-CGI as a work-around.

        '; exit; } 
    /** * Error reporting */ 
    error_reporting( /*E_ALL | E_STRICT */ 0); 
    /** * Compilation includes configuration file */ 
    define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd()); $compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php'; 
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) { include $compilerConfig; } $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php'; $maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag'; if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) { if (is_dir('downloader')) { header("Location: downloader"); } else { echo $mageFilename." was not found"; } exit; } if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) { include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php'; exit; } require_once $mageFilename; #Varien_Profiler::enable(); if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) { Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); } #ini_set('display_errors', 1); umask(0); 
    /* Store or website code */ 
    $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : ''; 
    /* Run store or run website */ $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store'; Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

For the past week i tried and make the following things:

1. installed a php_curl fix for the php version. The php_curl extension works because when i am installing a fresh copy of magento it works fine.
2. i checked the list of all system requierments for installing Magento and the php extensions are all working.
3. i changed the memory_limit in php.ini from 128M to 512M.
4. i modified the local.xml file from app/etc to point to my localhost and db_name, db_user, db_pass that i created localy for this store.
5. i imported the database from the live server in my local database and modified the base_url options from core_config table
6. i turned on the apache modules headers_module, rewrite_module, include_module and php5_module.
7. i tried edit the .htaccess to rewrite_base but nothing changed.
8. i tried comment out from .htaccess   AddType x-mapp-php5 .php and AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php from .htaccess but nothing displays after that so i leaved the as they were, uncommented.
9. i used like 4-5 versions of php and apache.. but nothing worked.

Now one last thing.. in my apache error log.. the last thing that i get is the following line:

`[Fri Oct 25 11:50:14 2013] [warn] Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'`

Please help me with this issue.
Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: have you added any virtualhost to run magento on ? if yes please copy that too

Comment: What you see there is the content of `index.php` from Magento. Most likely you don't have PHP installed on your server.

Comment: I added virtual hosts but didn't work so i modified it back to the usual hosts. The host looked like this:
127.0.0.1    http://localhost/mysite/ @SKV

Comment: I have php installed on my server because i am using wamp to programm other things like custom mvc's, wordpress, and fresh magento installation. They all work fine @Marius

Comment: Dragos this the configuration from host file, have you inserted any code in xamp's vhost-httpd file ?

Comment: No.. i didn't. I need to mention that i don't run xamp. I am using wamp.. @SKV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running magento on localhost as follows:

check your device IP and add following lines to windows/system32/drivers/etchosts file

```
192.168.1.59       magento.hue
192.168.1.59       www.magento.hue
```

please change IP's accordingly.

then go to you-xamp-installation/apache/conf-extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

and add following

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.59:80
<VirtualHost magento.hue>
    ServerAdmin magento.hue
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/mag_domain/"
    ServerName magento.hue
    ServerAlias www.magento.hue
    ErrorLog "C:/www/mag_domain/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/www/mag_domain/access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:/www/mag_domain">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

where suppose C:/www/mag_domain/ is the path to folder where you have downloaded your live site. change accordingly.

Import db to your local mysql and change the username/password etc in app/etc/local.xml

then try running http://magento.hue on browser and let know the outcome.

please try with a fresh bunch of magento site and db, in case you have changed something in it.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I talked with some friends and they asked me to put the same copy of the store on a different server. I uploaded and configured the store on a subdomain on my development server. The same thing. Some friends told me it's a php problem in the core or in one of the modules so i disabled the modules one by one and all togheter and nothing worked. I think there is a problem with the php code but i can't figure out where. At least i know it's not a config file or server issue. @SKV

Comment: you can also rename you core Mage folder and upload from a fresh download of a same version, might work.

Comment: last try, rename zend folder too.. and manually delete all files inside session, cache, locks etc. check if this works.

Comment: nothing. done that too. thanks for you time. i appreciate your help @SKV